# Unable to locate mat-option selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium web driver to automate an angular website. The thing is the site has 3 dropdowns, 1 for Country, 1 for Province and 1 for City.

I know that I can't use the Select class, so the first thing I'm doing is clicking on the mat-select element, and after that, I click on the mat-option that I want.

The problem is that sometimes when I run the test the id, xpath or cssSelector is different for the mat-option.

How can I guarantee the access to the same mat-option all the time?

HTML for mat-select

```
<mat-select _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c19-42 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" formcontrolname="country" placeholder="Seleccione un país" role="listbox" id="mat-select-5" tabindex="0" aria-label="Seleccione un país" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-multiselectable="false">
    <div class="mat-select-trigger" aria-hidden="true" cdk-overlay-origin="">
        <div class="mat-select-value">
            <!----><span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c19-42 ng-star-inserted">Seleccione un país</span>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper">
            <div class="mat-select-arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
</mat-select>
```

After I click on the mat-select it changes to this

```
<mat-select _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c19-42 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" formcontrolname="country" placeholder="Seleccione un país" role="listbox" id="mat-select-5" tabindex="0" aria-label="Seleccione un país" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-owns="mat-option-344 mat-option-345 mat-option-346 mat-option-347 mat-option-348 mat-option-349 mat-option-350 mat-option-351 mat-option-352 mat-option-353 mat-option-354 mat-option-355 mat-option-356 mat-option-357 mat-option-358 mat-option-359 mat-option-360 mat-option-361 mat-option-362 mat-option-363 mat-option-364 mat-option-365 mat-option-366 mat-option-367 mat-option-368 mat-option-369 mat-option-370 mat-option-371 mat-option-372 mat-option-373 mat-option-374 mat-option-375 mat-option-376 mat-option-377 mat-option-378 mat-option-379 mat-option-380 mat-option-381 mat-option-382 mat-option-383 mat-option-384 mat-option-385 mat-option-386 mat-option-387 mat-option-388 mat-option-389 mat-option-390 mat-option-391 mat-option-392 mat-option-393 mat-option-394 mat-option-395 mat-option-396 mat-option-397 mat-option-398 mat-option-399 mat-option-400 mat-option-401 mat-option-402 mat-option-403 mat-option-404 mat-option-405 mat-option-406 mat-option-407 mat-option-408 mat-option-409 mat-option-410 mat-option-411 mat-option-412 mat-option-413 mat-option-414 mat-option-415 mat-option-416 mat-option-417 mat-option-418 mat-option-419 mat-option-420 mat-option-421 mat-option-422 mat-option-423 mat-option-424 mat-option-425 mat-option-426 mat-option-427 mat-option-428 mat-option-429 mat-option-430 mat-option-431 mat-option-432 mat-option-433 mat-option-434 mat-option-435 mat-option-436 mat-option-437 mat-option-438 mat-option-439 mat-option-440 mat-option-441 mat-option-442 mat-option-443 mat-option-444 mat-option-445 mat-option-446 mat-option-447 mat-option-448 mat-option-449 mat-option-450 mat-option-451 mat-option-452 mat-option-453 mat-option-454 mat-option-455 mat-option-456 mat-option-457 mat-option-458 mat-option-459 mat-option-460 mat-option-461 mat-option-462 mat-option-463 mat-option-464 mat-option-465 mat-option-466 mat-option-467 mat-option-468 mat-option-469 mat-option-470 mat-option-471 mat-option-472 mat-option-473 mat-option-474 mat-option-475 mat-option-476 mat-option-477 mat-option-478 mat-option-479 mat-option-480 mat-option-481 mat-option-482 mat-option-483 mat-option-484 mat-option-485 mat-option-486 mat-option-487 mat-option-488 mat-option-489 mat-option-490 mat-option-491 mat-option-492 mat-option-493 mat-option-494 mat-option-495 mat-option-496 mat-option-497 mat-option-498 mat-option-499 mat-option-500 mat-option-501 mat-option-502 mat-option-503 mat-option-504 mat-option-505 mat-option-506 mat-option-507 mat-option-508 mat-option-509 mat-option-510 mat-option-511 mat-option-512 mat-option-513 mat-option-514 mat-option-515 mat-option-516 mat-option-517 mat-option-518 mat-option-519 mat-option-520 mat-option-521 mat-option-522 mat-option-523 mat-option-524 mat-option-525 mat-option-526 mat-option-527 mat-option-528 mat-option-529 mat-option-530 mat-option-531 mat-option-532 mat-option-533 mat-option-534 mat-option-535 mat-option-536 mat-option-537 mat-option-538 mat-option-539 mat-option-540 mat-option-541 mat-option-542 mat-option-543 mat-option-544 mat-option-545 mat-option-546 mat-option-547 mat-option-548 mat-option-549 mat-option-550 mat-option-551 mat-option-552 mat-option-553 mat-option-554 mat-option-555 mat-option-556 mat-option-557 mat-option-558 mat-option-559 mat-option-560 mat-option-561 mat-option-562 mat-option-563 mat-option-564 mat-option-565 mat-option-566 mat-option-567 mat-option-568 mat-option-569 mat-option-570 mat-option-571 mat-option-572 mat-option-573 mat-option-574 mat-option-575 mat-option-576 mat-option-577 mat-option-578 mat-option-579 mat-option-580 mat-option-581 mat-option-582 mat-option-583 mat-option-584 mat-option-585 mat-option-586 mat-option-587 mat-option-588 mat-option-589" aria-activedescendant="mat-option-344">
    <div class="mat-select-trigger" aria-hidden="true" cdk-overlay-origin="">
        <div class="mat-select-value">
            <!----><span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c19-42 ng-star-inserted">Seleccione un país</span>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper">
            <div class="mat-select-arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
</mat-select>
```

And the element mat-option looks like this

```
<mat-option _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-407" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <!----><span class="mat-option-text"> ESPAÑA </span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
</mat-option>
```

Java code

```
By cmbPais = By.xpath("//*[@id='mat-select-0']/div/div[1]"); // Country dropdown
By selectPais = By.cssSelector("#mat-option-63"); // Option dropdown

// select the country
driver.findElement(cmbPais).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(selectPais).click();
```

This works, but the mat-option doesn't have always the same behavior (sometimes the cssLocator is different, also the id and the xpath), so when that happens the test doesn't select the country that I want, selects another one.

Comment: add html code snip instead screenshot its bad practice how someone can write html  code to reproduce your java problem

Comment: Do you mean the whole HTML code of the site?

Comment: NO, the elements you highlighting in screenshot those only :)

Comment: Ok, then is ready :)

Comment: You didn't talk about the specific locators you have tried and what the results were. Saying you used CSS selectors and XPaths isn't terribly specific or helpful.

Comment: I edit and add the information :)

Answer (score 5):

The `mat-select` clearly has an ID, `id="mat-select-5"`, so that should always be your first choice for the select. For the options, if the IDs are changing, we'll have to find another way to locate them. By contained text seems like a good thing to start with.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-5")).click(); // opens the dropdown
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-option/span[contains(.,'ESPAÑA')]")).click(); // clicks on 'ESPAÑA' option
```

I would suggest that you put this into a function that you can use to set the country dropdown and then pass in the country name you want to select. You can then build that into the second click and use this for any country.

```
public void selectCountry(String countryName)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-5")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-option/span[contains(.,'" + countryName + "')]")).click();
}
```

and then you would call it like

```
selectCountry("ESPAÑA");
```

Answer (score 4):

After click action performed on dropdown element it renders some html and leads to change its attributes still there are some attributes which are not changed like `placeholder` Use xath to click on city dropdown element using placeholder

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-select[@placeholder='Seleccione un país']").click();
```

now to make sure option elements are visible and available to click can be checked using wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()=' ESPAÑA ']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()=' ESPAÑA ']").click();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!!It helped me :) I am a .NET Person.

Answer (score 0):

If your options always appear on the page in the same order, you can use that to select the one you want.

For example, to select the 3rd option:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//mat-option)[3]"));
```

Comment: There options are always in the same order but the Xpath is not always the same, for example, for the first country I got 3 different. I've tried with cssSelector and didn't work <mat-option _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-344" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false"><!----><span class="mat-option-text"> AFGANISTÁN </span><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div></mat-option>

Comment: Second:  <mat-option _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-23" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false"><!----><span class="mat-option-text"> AFGANISTÁN </span><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div></mat-option>

Comment: Third: <mat-option _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-0" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false"><!----><span class="mat-option-text"> AFGANISTÁN </span><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div></mat-option>